# How to count all null values of right join by nesting it?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT COUNT(Orders.EmployeeID) 
FROM Orders 
WHERE (Orders.EmployeeID IS NULL) 
  AND (IN(SELECT Orders.EmployeeID
          FROM Orders
          RIGHT JOIN Employees ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID)) 
GROUP BY Orders.EmplyoeeID;
```

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense to me, because you are counting the join column, which would either be non NULL or would have some value.  Please add data to your question.

Comment: are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ? Is this your current query ?

Comment: And note that nobody ever uses right join anyway. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You need to say us which DBMS are you using? MySQL or SQL Server? You have tagged both!

**In SQL Server:**

```
SELECT COUNT(   CASE
                    WHEN Orders.EmployeeID IS NULL THEN 1
                    ELSE NULL
                END
            )
FROM Orders
    RIGHT JOIN Employees
        ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID;
```

If you pass a column name to the `COUNT` function, it wont count the null values, so in order to count the NULL values, you can use `CASE` to determine the NULL values and make `COUNT` function to count them(`WHEN Orders.EmployeeID IS NULL THEN 1`) and also you need to determine the non-NULL values and make make `COUNT` function not to count them(`ELSE NULL`).

Read more about `COUNT` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017